# How to build AWS Freertos with MPLAB for PIC32MZ1025W104

Tags: pic, freertos, microchip, mplab, mplab-5.45

It seem to be missing the processor ports file, referenced in ports_p32xxxx.h.

`../../../../../vendors/microchip/harmony/v2.05/framework/peripheral/ports/processor/ports_p32xxxx.h:779:6: error: #error Unknown processor! #error Unknown processor!`

Anyone know where i should be able to find this file?

Thanks,
Marcus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this is not fully supported, only special AWS demo software can be used at this stage, will need to wait for the supported release which is currently in the works.